# How deploy UWP app like we did WPF from windows server?

Tags: uwp, setup-deployment

I am new in UWP deployment need the right way to do this
I want to deploy my UWP to my users through group policy like we did WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from [Distribute LOB apps to enterprises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises) document.

> There are several options for distributing line of business (LOB) apps to your organization’s users using MSIX packages without making the apps broadly available to the public.

And [App Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises#app-installer) is suit for your scenario that double-clicking an .appinstaller file that installs the app package from a web server. For the detail steps you could refer to  [**Installing Windows 10 apps from a web page**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web) document.

**Update**

For your comment questions, You could refer to [**Deploy an Application from Windows Store for Business via System Center Configuration Manager**](http://Deploy%20an%20Application%20from%20Windows%20Store%20for%20Business%20via%20System%20Center%20Configuration%20Manager) document.

> you can take the .appx file for an app that has been made available for Offline use, and distribute the app with a management tool such as **System Center Configuration Manager** or the Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer.

Comment: from App Installer ".appxbundle" is created.. so this file can we deploy through management tools?

Comment: Yes, i understand,, I have few questions.. 1) Basically I want to deploy my UWP app like we are doing with WPF MSI... i want something like MSI that can install through command line without any UI or i can easily install that for many users from one place...So i need to create MSIX for that if yes how to create MSIX for UWP application. 2) its is possible to deploy ".appxbundle" file through Management tools like Citrix?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update.. can we install this Appx from CMD?

Comment: We recommend use powershell to install appx package. you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps).